# C++11: accessing member functions from vector of vectors

Tags: c++11

How to access functions of this class from a vector of vectors?

`someNamespace::SomeClass *test;
test->doSomething();`

If I want to have multiple instances of the same class, I am giving it like this:

`std::vector< std::vector<someNamespace::SomeClass> > test;`
`test.resize(SomeValueofSize_t);`

The number of instances of "test" is known at runtime.

This is how I am accessing `doSomething()` now.

`test[0][0].doSomething();`

The code compiles, but I am not sure if that is the correct way to do

Comment: For the code you have shown it wouldn't be correct. You resize `test` which gives you a bunch of empty vectors. `test[0]` gives you the first of them and then `test[0][0]` tries to access the first `someNamespace::SomeClass` of that first vector, but since it is empty the element doesn't exist. But maybe that is only because you simplified the code too much. The accessing syntax itself is correct.

Comment: So would it be correct to continue to access: test[i][0]; or is it always test[0][i]; where i is an iterator.

Comment: They do different things. `test[i][0]` iterates over the vectors and looks at the first element of each. `test[0][i]` iterates over all elements of the first vector. Which one is correct depends on what you want to do.

Comment: If I always want to access `doSomething()` for different `test`, i'd do test[i][0].

Comment: Sure, you can do that. But using `test[0][i].doSomething()` will also access `doSomething` for different `someNamespace::SomeClass`s. If you want to call that on all of them you will need to use 2 loops and do `test[i][j].doSomething()`. Unless you know your first `vector` must have exactly 1 element, but in this case you shouldn't be using a `vector` for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me why you have a two-dimensional vector of class objects, but to do what you ask, you should iterate over both dimensions like @nwp suggested.

Assuming that you have a vector of vector of objects `someClass` called `test` as opposed to pointers to `someClass` instances i.e. `std::vector <std::vector <someNamespace::SomeClass> > test;` you would just iterate over them like this and make your call to `doSomething()`.  If `doSomething()` has to modify the `test` object, just remove the `const`.

```
for (const auto& element : test)
{
    for (const auto& obj : element)
    {
        obj.doSomething();
    }
}
```